# Bootstrap navbar not collapsing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting started with Bootstrap and its navbars.

I'm trying to get its responsive menu working however its not working as expected. The menu in small windows loads expanded and the menu toggle does not work. I have loaded all the necessary dependancies but something still is not quite right.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2bv9noe/2/)

HTML:

```
        <!-- Static navbar -->
           <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
             <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
               </div>
               <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
                   <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top</a></li>
                   <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
             </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine http://www.bootply.com/KPa5Y4MFal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ypu are missing collapse class on the navbar

This list:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
               <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top</a></li>
               <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
             </ul>
```

needs to be wrapped in:

```
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Also the fiddle you provided has incorrect JS and CSS includes. Take a look at this example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rbd8758f/

Comment: even after wrapping that code in that line its still the same. check http://jsfiddle.net/b2bv9noe/2/

Comment: i am looking into it, something else is messed up, i found that copying examples from http://bootsnipp.com/ helped a ton and then go in and modify bit by bit what you need

Comment: Its weird because I just copied and pasted that HTML code from one of the bootstrap example pages

Comment: When you say that the JS and CSS is wrong, do you mean they are missing classes and functions? The resources I've used are custom picked from the Bootstrap custom download as all I needed from there was the grid system and the responsive menus.

Comment: Yes, it seems you were missing required components for the menu to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you put meta tag in your header, this worked for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">.
```